# (Python/rich) restore cursor default values on exit

Tags: python, terminal, rich

I have a Python3.9+ project that runs on the command line on both Linux and Windows. I use [rich](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to interact with the console.
Out of curiosity I would like to know if it is possible to save the characteristics of the console cursor at the beginning of the program (at least, is the cursor visible ?) and to modify the console cursor according to these characteristics (at the end of the program).

I found nothing in the [documentation](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/console.html).

Comment: What kind of characteristics were you thinking of?

Comment: @WillMcGugan : I have updated my question. I was thinking of the following features: is the cursor visible? how big is it? how does it look?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I also used rich with python (3.8) and when my program exited, the terminal cursor was invisible. only `reset` will bring it back.
I ended up registering an "atexit" hook that prints terminal control code that restore the terminal cursor.

```
atexit.register(lambda: print("\x1b[?25h"))
```

This worked for me, Though I wish rich will have an option to restore the terminal settings on exit.

Comment: did not work for me, in iterm.